# Does absolute version of put() for for direct int buffer require synchronization?

Tags: java, thread-safety, direct-buffer

I have a use of direct buffers, where a direct buffer is allocated and use like this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);
IntBuffer buffer1 = buffer.asIntBuffer();
buffer1.limit(1024);
buffer.position(4096);
IntBuffer buffer2 = buffer.asIntBuffer();
```

Then both buffer1 and buffer2 can be used from multiple threads with absolute get and put. It seems like nothing in the documentation specifies that reads and writes would be atomic (in the same sense as writing and reading a regular java array, ignoring visibility) in such a case, even though as far as I can tell from the underlying implementation it is going to be.

In this use case, if it was a regular java array, I wouldn't need any extra synchronization for accessing it as other existing synchronization would guarantee happens-before relationship. With direct buffers, as far as I can see, going strictly by the documentation, it seems like I would need to synchronize access to those buffers. Am I missing something that would allow me to skip synchronization?

Comment: Reading file in Multi-threading is slower than Single thread solution.

Comment: @AnotherOne This isn't actually about multithreading reading a file. The 2 buffers are just different logical sections of data. While the code is related to file access, it isn't an attempt at just "multithreading read/write".

Comment: If you're working from a single thread, there is never any need for synchronization.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There are multiple threads. There *may* be 2 threads doing a read from the same file (random access), or 2 threads, one trying to read and one trying to write to a different part of the file. I also should have clarified, it's single element get/put. Either way I may just delete this question because the performance impact of additionally locking this may be small enough to not really matter, just completely unnecessarily makes the code more complex.. And I'm probably going to delete this question because I don't want to explain in so much detail everything I'm doing and why

Comment: Then you are multi-threading, but - I assume - not with the same buffer shared between threads, and the locking logic of the filesystem itself should be sufficient for this (unless you want to be 100% sure some actions happen in a specific order, but then synchronization wouldn't be sufficient either).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There is a moment where an in memory structure (held in those buffers) is updated from writer thread, while readers don't hold the same lock at the moment of reading that data from memory. This would be fine with java arrays as either the old or the new int would be visible, and either is fine in that state. But seems like direct buffers don't allow me to do that

Comment: @MarkRotteveel to further clarify, reading never actually reads that structure directly from disk except for initialization (doesn't need to deal with threads) and writing code updates it on disk after modifying it in memory.

Comment: OK, then you will need to apply synchronization as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Does that also apply to absolute get() from multiple threads theoretically not being safe? (ie. would a ReadWriteLock be ok for example, ignoring whether it would be beneficial)

Comment: Even then, given you're sharing the buffer, without synchronization if one thread is writing to a location and another is reading from that same location, the reader might see 1) the value before the write, 2) the value after the write or 3) some bytes of the new value and some bytes of the old value. Items 1 and 2 are "correct" (depending on your needs), but item 3 is problematic. Multiple reads will not interfere with each other, so a `ReadWriteLock` will do as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As far as I can tell, the implementation makes 3 impossible - buffers allocation is always aligned in practice and aligned writes and reads of ints are atomic, but nothing in the documentation actually allows me to consider it safe. In other words, I know that in on any real world implementation of java I'm aware of this will work, but seems like the documentation never specifies it. And that was my main question - am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, you might be right, if you're right about alignment (or if the platform directly supports unaligned access), but there is a case in `DirectByteBuffer.asIntBuffer` that deals with unaligned access where writes of an int will be performed with individual `putByte` calls, which would not be atomic. But if that is not the case in practice, then yes, the write should be atomic, and item 3 is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`Buffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#thread-safety-heading) contains this statement about thread safety:

> **Thread safety**
>
> Buffers are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. If a buffer is to be used by more than one thread then access to the buffer should be controlled by appropriate synchronization.

No subclass of `Buffer` contains any additional statements about thread safety, so you must assume that this statement also applies to direct buffers and its varaints.